# Multiple return values with arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, return-value, multiple-return-values

I believe arrays are mostly used for returning multiple values from methods:

```
def some_method
  return [1, 2]
end

[a, b] = some_method # should yield a = 1 and b = 2
```

I presume this is a kind of syntactic sugar that Ruby provides. Can we get a similar result with hashes, for instance

```
def some_method
  return { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }
end

{"c", "d"} = some_method() # "c" => 1, "d" => 2
```

I'm looking for the result `{ "c" => 1, "d" => 2 }`, which obviously does not happen. Is there any other way this can be done? I know that we can return a hash from the method and store it and use it like so

```
def some_method
  return {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
end

hash = some_method()
```

Just curious if there is another way similar to the one with arrays but using hashes....

---

I think a simpler way to put the question would be...

```
    # If we have a hash
    hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

    # Is the following possible
    hash = {2, 3} # directly assigning values to the hash.
    OR
    # another example
    {"c", "d"} = {2, 3} # c and d would be treated as keys and {2, 3} as respective values.
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Not even by overloading the '=' operator

Comment: Not clear where the `"c" ` and `"d"` in the result `{"c" => 1, "d" => 2}` are supposed to come from in your proposing form `hash = some_method()`.

Comment: That was just a raw example of how i wanted the operation to happen...something like... ruby would internally accept 'c' and 'd' as the keys and take the values from the assigned hash. Just wanted to know if it was possible. Thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is syntactically not possible.

What you want to accomplish is possible, but you will have to code it.
One possible way to do that is shown below

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

# Assign new keys
new_keys = ["c", "d"]
p [new_keys, hash.values].transpose.to_h
#=> {"c"=>1, "d"=>2}

# Assign new values
new_values = [3, 4]
p [hash.keys, new_values].transpose.to_h
#=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>4}
```

If you really want some more easier looking way of doing, you could monkey-patch `Hash` class and define new methods to manipulate the values of `keys` and `values` array.  Please be cautioned that it may not be really worthwhile to mess with core classes.  Anyways, a possible implementation is shown below.  **Use at your own RISK.**

```
class Hash
    def values= new_values
        new_values.each_with_index do |v, i|
            self[keys[i]] = v if i < self.size
        end
    end
    def keys= new_keys
        orig_keys = keys.dup
        new_keys.each_with_index do |k, i|
            if i < orig_keys.size
                v = delete(orig_keys[i])
                self[k] = v
                rehash
            end
        end
    end
end

hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

hash.values = [2,3]
p hash
#=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>3}

hash.keys = ["c", "d"]
p hash
#=> {"c"=>2, "d"=>3}

hash.keys, hash.values = ["x","y"], [9, 10]
p hash
#=> {"x"=>9, "y"=>10}

hash.keys, hash.values = ["x","y"], [9, 10]
p hash
#=> {"x"=>9, "y"=>10}

# *** results can be unpredictable at times ***
hash.keys, hash.values = ["a"], [20, 10]
p hash
#=> {"y"=>20, "a"=>10}
```

Comment: Thanks...I'll give it a go...hopefully learn something new and mess up my ruby installation. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a syntax error. Instead of this:

```
[a, b] = [1, 2]
```

you should use:

```
a, b = [1, 2]
```

And if you want to use similar syntax with hashes, you can do:

```
a, b = { "c" => 1, "d" => 2 }.values     # a => 1, b => 2
```

This is actually the same thing as the array version, beacause `Hash#values` returns an array of the hash values in the order they were inserted to the hash (because ruby hashes have a nice feature of preserving their order)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the syntax error. So only arrays can be used and not hashes to store the results.

Comment: I thought hashes never preserved order. Also I was looking towards assigning the hash to a hash. In the answer that you provided. [a, b] is still assigned an array [1, 2]. Here a and b can be used as variables. Hoped ruby had similar features for hashes as well

Comment: @jc_john AFAIK, only arrays work for this. It's actually ambiguous to use a hash directly because it's a key-value data structure. How would ruby determine if you want to store the keys, the values, or a combination of both. so in my example above you could use `{ "c" => 1, "d" =>2}.keys` and the keys would be assigned instead of the values.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. Could you look at the last segment of the question.

Comment: @jc_john FWIW hashes are ordered since Ruby 1.9.